# Differentiate string parameter from variable which is referencing to a string

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to differentiate literal string passed as parameter from variable which is referencing to a string value in JavaScript ? I think this is not possible but maybe there is way.

For example:

```
var myString = 'some string'

function whoIsThat(x){ 
  alert(typeof(x)) 
};

whoIsThat(myString) // differentiate this ?
whoIsThat('some string')  // from this ?
```

Comment: No, there's not. Why do you want to? BTW, `typeof` is an operator, not a function, and does not require parentheses in this case.

Comment: I'm with @torazaburo - why would you care?

Comment: Not with a literal string and a variable referencing to a string. Which in this case is replaced by the variable `x` anyways. Although you could if you used a `String` object. `var myString = new String('some string');`

Comment: not is possible, what you want to do ?

Comment: Ok, I copy this code from another forum, I just have some discussion about this and I was thinking that this is not possible to do. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used only a literal string passed as parameter for a variable, and a literal string itself:

```
var myString = 'some string'
'some string'
```

Then there isn't a way to tell the difference between them. Also note that both of these are passed to a local variable `x` anyways. Although if you made a slight modification and use a `String` Object instead. Then the difference is easy:

```
var myString = new String('some string');

function whoIsThat(x){ 
  alert(typeof(x)) 
};

whoIsThat(myString);       // -> object
whoIsThat('some string');  // -> string
```